# Laravel Recaptcha greggilbert not setting public key

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I´m using Recaptcha greggilbert in Laravel 5.2, but its not adding the public key, but public and private key are set in */config/recaptcha.php*

```
 {!! Recaptcha::render() !!}

--Result--

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="" ></div>
```

If i change *curl_timeout* to *2* on */config/recaptcha.php*, it changes the value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well just a dumb typo:

In */config/recaptha.php*:

```
Instead of doing this:

'public_key'     => env('RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY', 'KEY'),
'private_key'    => env('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY', 'KEY), 

I did this:

'public_key'     => env('KEY', ''),
'private_key'    => env('KEY', ''),
```